# getItem vs. getItemAtPosition

Tags: android, performance

There are 2 ways of getting selected Item of a list view.

1. `list.getAdapter().getItem(position);`
2. `list.getItemAtPosition(position)`

My question is, which one is the preferred way of doing it?

I've seen people use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use which one you want. `getItemAtPosition(position)` basically makes a call to the adapter with `getItem(position)`, it's the same thing.

Comment: so technicly, the 1st is 0.0000000001 ms faster, 1 less function call :) Thanks

Comment: @eric.itzhak Yes, you could look at it that way, but let's be serious, this isn't the stuff that will make your app lighting fast :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the implementation of `getItemAtPosition()` from the source code of `ListView`.

```
public Object getItemAtPosition(int position) {
  T adapter = getAdapter();
  return (adapter == null || position < 0) ? null : adapter.getItem(position);
}
```

So basically they are same.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are incorrect, there is one big difference.

When you add a header to a ListView the ListView wraps the adapter in a HeaderViewListAdapter. HeaderViewListAdapter's job is translating `position` to take the headers into account.

For example, if you have added one header `position 1` corresponds to the underlying adapter's `position 0`. If you tried to use adapter.getItem(position) it would actually return you the second item in the adapter.

If you've added a header you have to use listView.getItemAtPosition(position).

Comment: I've based my answer on the source code of the ListView widget(which you can find on the other answer as well). Care to explain how does getItemAtPosition()(which calls the adapter's getItem() method) make a difference from simply calling the adapter's(no matter the type of the adapter) getItem() method? Did you test what you claim?

Comment: I explained the difference in my answer.