# Android ListView Populated from XML won't send data to new activity

Tags: android, xml, arrays, android-intent

I have an array located in my strings.xml file that looks like the following.

```
<string-array name="array123">
<item>test1</item>
<item>test2</item>
<item>test3</item>
<item>test4</item>
<item>test5</item>
</string-array>
```

My listview is properly displayed on Activity 1, here is my onItemClick code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
String selectedItem = adapter.getSelectedItem().toString();
activityIntent.putExtra("my.package.dataToPass", selectedItem);
startActivity(activityIntent);
```

As soon as I tap an item from the list the screen just goes black and the application crashes. Here is my code for Activity 2

```
Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
String myVal = recdData.getString("my.package.dataToPass");
TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
word.setText(myVal);
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm just trying to pass the string that was selected to show as text on the 2nd activity. I've been searching for a day and a half now.
I did try

```
activityIntent.putExtra("my.package.dataToPass", id);
```

but this just seemed to pass an empty screen.
Any help would be much appreciated. Obviously I'm not passing the right data in the intent.

Comment: btw: there's no real benefit from using bundle keys like `my.package.dataToPass` instead of just `dataToPass` (or even better `selectedId`). it will not clash as key is local to that bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you are implementing the Click listener (`onItemClick`) rather than Select listener(`onItemSelected`). By default when you click on a `ListView` item it doesn't change its state to "selected"

Plz use `adapter.getItem(position)` instead of `adapter.getSelectedItem()`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    String selectedItem  = adapter.getItem(position).toString();
}
```

Comment: When I change from adapter.getSelectedItem() to adapter.getItem(position) my IDE says cannot resolve method 'getItem(int)'

Comment: plz paste the logcat.

Comment: Here is what is in the logcat when it crashes
AndroidRuntime at com.namespace.application.Class.onItemClick(Class.java:43)
I had to keep onItemClick as opposed to getItem, because getItem throws an error in the IDE therefore I can't run and debug the app.

Comment: plz add the complete stacktrace as an edit to your question. This is not enough.

Comment: Ritesh I'm giving you credit because you got me in the right direction. What fixed mine was using    adapter.getItemAtPosition(position) as opposed to    adapter.getItem(position) Thank you for your help

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved, however I would suggest you to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473266/getitem-vs-getitematposition